# Нужна ли запятая после «да» в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, цитирование

> Я говорю "да"(,) после чего кладу книгу на столик.

Нужна ли запятая, или она поглощается?

Answer (score 4):

***Я говорю "да", после чего кладу книгу на столик.***
В этом предложении запятая ничем не поглощается. Кавычки никаким образом не могут отменить её постановку.

Из [**вопроса № 303283**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=303283) на Грамоте.ру:

> *Он бросил сухое "привет", после чего сразу перешёл к делу.*
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Предложение оформлено верно.

Можно оформить и так (с прямой речью):
*Я говорю: "Да", после чего кладу книгу на столик.*

Answer (score 2):

[*Да*](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B0) — это утвердительный ответ. *Твёрдое, удивлённое, недоверчивое "да". Получить в ответ да.*

Кавычки обрамляют слово "да", запятая стоит между однородными сказуемыми — никакие знаки не съедаются.
Подобные предложения есть в правиле Розенталя (разъяснения, правда, даются по другому поводу):

> **1. Точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие** и **тире** ставятся только после закрывающих кавычек: *Одни голосовали «за», другие «против», но первые составляли большинство; Хватит с меня ваших «но», я ими сыт по горло...*

*Когда меня журналисты спрашивают о знакомстве со Спиваковым, я говорю "нет", потому что невозможно снова и снова повторять одно и то же...* (Сати Спивакова. Не всё).

[§ 66. Кавычки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175#pp175)